# error when try to insert data into database

Tags: php

HTML code

```
<form id="form1" name="addAnnouncement" method="post" action="ownerAddAnnouncement_exec.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
  <label style="font-size:18px">Title:
  <input type="text" name="title" />
  </label>
  <p>
  <label style="margin-left: -36px; font-size:18px;">Description:
  <textarea name="description" rows="6" cols="60"></textarea>
  </label>
  </p>
  <label style="font-size:18px">Date & Time: <br>
  From
  <input type="text" name="from" /> <br>
  To <input type="text" name="to" />
  </label>  <br>
  <label style="font-size:18px">Venue
  <input type="text" name="venue" />
  </label>        
  <p>
  <label>
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
  </label>
  </p>
  </fieldset>
  </form>
```

PHP code

```
<?php


$title = $_POST['title'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
$from = $_POST['from'];
$to = $_POST['to'];
$venue = $_POST['venue'];


$link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die();
$db = mysql_select_db("condo") or die("no database found");
$insert_sql="INSERT INTO announcement (title, description, from, to,venue, status)
             VALUES('$title', '$description', '$from', '$to','$venue', 'Pending')"; 

$sql_result=mysql_query($insert_sql) or die("Error in inserting data due to ".mysql_error());

if($sql_result)
    echo "Succesfully insert new data. Please log in back";

        else
    echo "Error in inserting new data";
```

?>

an error like this **("Error in inserting data due to You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from, to, status) VALUES('melvin', 'sdsaadsd', 'wew', 'ewrerw', 'we3', 'Pendi' at line 1"  )**
is show out when try to insert a data into database.

Anyone please help me fix the code.i have been stuck at here for 1 hour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Display the field names with in **``**.

Convert the insert statement to

```
$insert_sql="INSERT INTO announcement (`title`, `description`, `from`, `to`,`venue`, `status`)
             VALUES('$title', '$description', '$from', '$to','$venue', 'Pending')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding current error it is about reserved keywords like **from** as field name, so to avoid it either rename your db column or enclose it in back-quotes like `from`

further you may face other errors as you are ignoring many good practices in your code, for example

- Validate user input before inserting into db
- remember to escape user input (sql injection)
- enclose field names in back-quotes
- and many others see http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/30-php-best-practices-for-beginners--net-6194

Comment: Please provide the fixed query, this type of answer should be placed on comment.

Answer (score 0):

You should escape reserved keywords using backticks. Currently, you are using the following reserved keywords - `From` and `To` Try this :-

```
$insert_sql="INSERT INTO `announcement` (`title`, `description`, `from`, `to`,`venue`, `status`)
         VALUES('$title', '$description', '$from', '$to','$venue', 'Pending')";
```

Answer (score 0):

`From` is a keyword. And also `To`. It is not recommended to use them. But if you can't avoid it and still want to use them, add backquote ` like below in your insert query :

INSERT INTO announcement (`title`, `description`, `from`, `to`, `status`)
             VALUES('$title', '$description', '$from', '$to', 'Pending')

Hope this helped.